# in app purchase non consumable product

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

I have written the following code.

But when i execute this code, i got log, which shows "no products available".
I am unable to find the reason.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

if ([SKPaymentQueue canMakePayments]) 
{

SKProductsRequest *productsRequest=[[SKProductsRequest alloc]initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithObject:@"com.cmp.name.prdt"]];

productsRequest.delegate=self;
[productsRequest start];

}

else {
NSLog(@"Parental Control are enabled");
}

}


-(IBAction)btnpurchase

{

NSString* isPurchased = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"com.cmp.name.prdt"];

if ([@"purchased" compare:isPurchased]==NSOrderedSame)
{

///do some task

}

else
{

SKPayment * payment=[SKPayment paymentWithProductIdentifier:@"com.cmp.name.prdt"];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addTransactionObserver:self];
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];

}

}


-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response

{

SKProduct *validProduct=nil;

int count=[response.products count];

if (count>0) {

validProduct=[response.products objectAtIndex:0];

}

else if(!validProduct)

{

NSLog(@"no products available");

}

}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{

for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaaction in transactions)

{

switch (transaaction.transactionState)

{

case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:

break;

case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaaction];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"purchased" forKey:@"com.cmp.name.prdt"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

break;

case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaaction];

break;

case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:

if (transaaction.error.code!=SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {

NSLog(@"Error encountered");

}

[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaaction];

break;

default:

break;

}

}

}
```

Could anyone help me out in this?

Comment: [response.products count] returning ZERO, means you are getting zero product info in products array.

Comment: If you aren't receiving any products, make sure you've set up everything correctly on the iOS Dev Center and iTunes Connect. Also double check you are passing the correct product ids to the products request.

Answer (score 1):

You can try out with following piece of code 
//PRODUCT REQUEST DELEGATE METHOD

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response
{

    NSLog(@"The product request didReceiveResponse :%@",[response description]);
    NSLog(@"The products are :%@",[response.products description]);

    NSLog(@"The invalidProductIdentifiers are:%@",[response.invalidProductIdentifiers description]);

    NSArray *products=response.products;


    for(SKProduct *currentProduct in products){

         NSLog(@"THE Product price is :%@",currentProduct.price);
         NSLog(@"THE Product description is :%@",currentProduct.localizedDescription);
         NSLog(@"THE Product title is :%@",currentProduct.localizedTitle);
         NSLog(@"THE Product's product identifier is :%@",currentProduct.productIdentifier);

         }

}
```

THIS WILL LOG THE PRODUCT DETAILS REGISTERED ON iTUNES CONNECT IN CONSOLE WINDOW

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Apple does not respond with any useful information about why your purchases do not show up.  I would go through this [checklist](http://tinyurl.com/5wunksx).  In my apps, things didn't work for a few days, then the suddenly started working.  Be sure your financial info is correct.